# What is the best way to read a csv and text file from S3 on AWS glue without having to read it as a Dynamic daataframe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue

I am trying to read a csv file that is in my S3 bucket. I would like to do some manipulations and then finally convert to a dynamic dataframe and write it back to S3.

This  is what I have tried so far:

Pure Python:

```
     Val1=""
     Val2=""
     cols=[]
     width=[]
     with open('s3://demo-ETL/read/data.csv') as csvfile:
     readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in readCSV:
         print(row)
              if ((Val1=="" ) & (Val2=="")):
                 Val1=row[0]
                 Val2=row[0]
                 cols.append(row[1])
                 width.append(int(row[4]))
    else:
         continues...
```

Here I get an error that says it cannot find the file in the directory at all.

Boto3:

```
     import boto3

     s3 = boto3.client('s3')
     data = s3.get_object(Bucket='demo-ETL', Key='read/data.csv')
     contents = data['Body'].read()
     print(contents)
          for row in content:
               if ((Val1=="" ) & (Val2=="")):
                 Val1=row[0]
                 Val2=row[0]
                 cols.append(row[1])
                 width.append(int(row[4]))
    else:
    continues...
```

Here it says index is out of range which is strange because I have 4 comma separated values in the csv file. When I look at the results from the print(contents), I see that its putting each character in a list, instead of it putting each comma separated value in a list.

Is there a better way to read the csv from s3?

Comment: Have you tried pandas or spark dataframe i.e, df=spark.read.csv("s3://demo-ETL/read/data.csv") . ?

Comment: I tried spark dataframe which didn't seem to be the best option. But pandas dataframe worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by reading it as a pandas dataframe. I first created an object with boto3, then read the whole object as a pd which I then converted into a list.

```
       s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
       bucket = s3.Bucket('demo-ETL')
       obj = bucket.Object(key='read/data.csv') 
       dataFrame = pd.read_csv(obj.get()['Body'])
       l = dataFrame.values.tolist()
           for i in l:
           print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) returns the `Body` response value which is of type [`StreamingBody`](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html). Per the docs, if you're trying to go line-by-line you probably want to use [`iter_lines`](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.iter_lines).

For example:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
data = s3.get_object(Bucket='demo-ETL', Key='read/data.csv')
file_lines = data['Body'].iter_lines()
print(file_lines)
```

This probably does more of what you want.

Comment: This reads the file and prints each line of data in string form. I would like the each of line to be in a list that way I can iterate over them as shown in the for loop above. I did this locally and I am looking for an equivalent way of doing it on glue. `with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV: print(rows)` This prints out each line like so 
    `['name', 'age', '2', '54', '9']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark to read the file like this:

```
df = spark.read.\
           format("csv").\
           option("header", "true").\
           load("s3://bucket-name/file-name.csv")
```

You can find more options here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv